# Need help writing a function to implement a .filter method on the array & return an array of names where the first name matches the argument nameQuery

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

Instructions: Create a function expression named `searchFirstNames`. The `searchFirstNames` function should contain parameters named `namesAr` and `nameQuery`. Within the `searchFirstNames` function implement a .filter method on the array called `namesAr` and return an array of names where the first name matches the argument `nameQuery`.

Example:
If names array contains the names `"Anthony Jackson"` and `"Jaco Pastorious"` and the `namesQuery` is `"Anthony"` then the result of calling the function `searchFirstNames` should be an array containing `"Anthony Jackson"`

Call the function `searchFirstNames` with the argument `fullNames` and `nameQuery` set to be `"John"` and store the resulting array into a variable named at your discretion.

My result: So, I called the function `searchFirstNames` with the arguments `fullNames` and `"John"` and I stored the resulting array into a variable called `matchingFirstNames`. Unfortunately, `matchingFirstNames` comes back as undefined when it should be an array containing `"John Smith"`.

```js
var getNames = function() {

  var names = ["Aled Ratcliffe",
    "Cassie Gibbons", "Ephraim Holman", "Asim Ayala", "Johnny Villegas", "Kanye Bond", "Leoni Akhtar", "Duane Velasquez", "Elana Stark", "John Smith"
  ];

  return names;
}

var fullNames = getNames();

var searchFirstNames = function(namesAr, nameQuery) {
  var nameToQuery = nameQuery;
  var matches = namesAr.filter(filterFirstNames);
  return matches;
}

function filterFirstNames(namesArr) {
  let nameObj = {};
  const nameParts = namesArr.split(" ");
  nameObj.fName = nameParts[0];
  nameObj.lName = nameParts[1];
  let result = false;
  if (namesArr.fName === nameToQuery) {
    result = true;
  }
  return result;
}

var matchingFirstNames = searchFirstNames(fullNames, "John");
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: nameToQuery is not defined` inside `filterFirstNames `....

Comment: how do I get access to `nameQuery` inside `filterFirstNames`?

Comment: You could create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures): https://jsfiddle.net/s5gnom18/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the `filterFirstNames` function inside `searchFirstNames`. Then it will be able to access the variable `namesQuery` (there's no need to declare a new variable `nameToQuery`).

You also had a typo: `namesArr.fName` should be `nameObj.fName`.

```js
var fullNames = ["Aled Ratcliffe",
  "Cassie Gibbons", "Ephraim Holman", "Asim Ayala", "Johnny Villegas", "Kanye Bond", "Leoni Akhtar", "Duane Velasquez", "Elana Stark", "John Smith"
]

var searchFirstNames = function(namesAr, nameQuery) {
  var matches = namesAr.filter(filterFirstNames);
  return matches;

  function filterFirstNames(namesArr) {
    let nameObj = {};
    const nameParts = namesArr.split(" ");
    nameObj.fName = nameParts[0];
    nameObj.lName = nameParts[1];
    let result = false;
    if (nameObj.fName === nameQuery) {
      result = true;
    }
    return result;
  }

}

var matchingFirstNames = searchFirstNames(fullNames, "John");
console.log(matchingFirstNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a closure and simplify the logic of the returned value:

```js
function getNames() {
  return ["Aled Ratcliffe",
    "Cassie Gibbons", "Ephraim Holman", "Asim Ayala", "Johnny Villegas", "Kanye Bond", "Leoni Akhtar", "Duane Velasquez", "Elana Stark", "John Smith"
  ];
}

const fullNames = getNames();

function searchFirstNames(namesAr, nameQuery) {
  return namesAr.filter(filterFirstNames(nameQuery));
}

function filterFirstNames(nameToQuery) {
  return namesArr => namesArr.split(" ")[0] === nameToQuery
}

const matchingFirstNames = searchFirstNames(fullNames, "John");
console.log(matchingFirstNames);
```